# AutoNumeric JQuery Plugin not allowing to insert decimal point once focus loss

Tags: jquery, autonumber

I am using jQuery [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) plugin to format number automatically in currency. It's working fine and converts number to currency. But once i loss focus from field and again i go to that field at that time it's not allowing me to type decimal point.

Any idea for this?

Here is my code:

```
$('#Amount').autoNumeric();

<input id="Amount" name="Amount" class="auto"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to work on the demo website, so there's not much we can do unless you show us your code or provide more information.

Comment: Now you can see my code. I have edited my question.

Comment: Just a guess, have you changed the separator "," to a ".", I notice that the plugin doesn't allow for more than one decimal point...

Comment: No i haven't changes a single character of that plugin file.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you . please try this

```
$('#Amount').autoNumeric('init',{aSign: '₹', dGroup: 2 });
```

here autoNumeric should be initiated when you are clicking on text box. Then you can set options like currency symbol